# FreeBSD 10: list packages without descriptions

Tags: package, freebsd

I need a way to print all packages installed on a FreeBSD 10 OS without the descriptions. Does such a command exist?

I've tried this:

```
pkg info
```

which does list all of the packages, but it also lists the descriptions like so:

```
pkg-1.5.4              Package manager
python26-2.7.9_1       Interpreted object-oriented programming language
....
```

Is is possible to print this info without the description? this would turn the above into this?

```
pkg-1.5.4
python26-2.7.9_1
....
```

Note: I'm on FreeBSD 10, which has replaced the `pkg_install`, `pkg_info`, etc. commands with `pkg install`, `pkg info`, etc

Comment: `pkg info -q`? This is what I use to complete pkg commands. I concede man page (pkg-info) is not really clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want a specific format, it is better to use the `pkg query` command (see [pkg-query(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-query&sektion=8)).

In your case, you want to list all the packages with the name and the version separated by '-'. Then the command should be `pkg query -a %n-%v` where `-a` list all the installed packages and `%n-%v` print the ouput with name-version format.

You can have more information on the QUERY FORMAT part of the man page.